# Combine and delete duplicate records in table with PSQL

Tags: duplicates, psql

I have a table of contacts:

```
Key |first | Last |   Dept    | ...
1    Mary    NULL    english
2    John    Fisher  math
3    Mary    Jones   NULL
```

How can I combine the separate records into one and delete the duplicates? like this:

```
Key |first | Last |   Dept    | ...
1    Mary    Jones   english
2    John    Fisher  math
```

I already know how to find the duplicates using:

```
SELECT first, last, dept
FROM Names
GROUP BY first, last, dept HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY first, last;
```

But combining is turning into a bit of a challenge

Comment: What do you mean with combine? Find all Marys that have no Dept entry and make it 'english'? That sounds a lot like guessing.

Comment: yeah I would like to be able to combine on first and last names there are a bunch of column headers in the table but I thought I could expand on it more if i got a good running start

Comment: Are you using PSQL or MySQL? Please use the correct tags.

Comment: If you have Mary Jones and Mary Smith, which one gets combined with Mary NULL?

Comment: What if you have another entry for a Mary NULL with 'french'?

Comment: Before we can give you any advice, you need to specify precisely how the merges are supposed to work. And maybe if you do that it will help you figure out how to code it yourself.

Comment: It seems that you need to flag any potential duplicates and let a real person mark them for combining.  That's a lot more work, but a lot safer, than having a program do it, especially with "a bunch of column headers".  Or maybe only combine if 90% of the fields match and the non-matching fields contain nulls.  Or delete ONLY if the rows are a 100% match.  How would combining affect any foreign key relationships?